# Set form values by default in angular4 using template driven approach

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I need to set my form values to some default values on loading of the page. I thought of doing it like this.

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@ViewChild('f') searchForm: NgForm;

ngOnInit() {
 this.searchForm.form.patchValue({
     keyword:'Cake',
     category:['Breakfast'],
     location:'Texas'
 }); 
}
```

But where do I need to include this code?

It doesn't set the value if I put it in ngOnInit() as shown. If I put it in ngDoCheck(), it sets the value, but it doesn't allow me to change the input.

Comment: perhaps as a workaround use `[ngModel]` instead?

Comment: I do not want to use ngModel since I need to do form handling. Is there a way to do it using form controls?

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can do *form handling* (whatever that means) dispite that. With `[ngModel]` you can just bind the default value and ignore it and do whatever you want after that.

Comment: I was just trying to do it without two way binding. I wanted a way where I could do it using form controls.

Comment: Okay, well I would suggest **one-way** binding and then just forget about it and then do youd *form handling*. If you truly want do it without any kind of ngModel, then I woud suggest a reactive form, which has many advantages compared to template-driven, in my opinion :)

Comment: Yes. I used reactive forms and now it works.